# SLIME 2.20 obsolete

Tags: package-repositories, slime

Why the status of SLIME 2.20 (Superior Lisp Interaction Mode for Emacs) is taged as obsolete in emacs melpa considering it actually is the newest version of SLIME right now (2017/11/20).[image]

Comment: Can you check whether Slime is listed more than once in the list?

Comment: @wasamasa Thanks for your advice. But after several restarts I can't recurrent the issue. Maybe it's a status update bug? I remmember that when this issue happened, there were two lines of **slime**, with one line highlighted in the picture and the other line is tagged as **installed**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed several versions of a package, Emacs will mark all but the newest as obsolete and offer deleting the obsolete ones as they're no longer needed (which you can do manually with `~`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My experience doesn't seems like what you describs (It's a pity that I can't reappearence that issue again even tried once and once.). But your answer really helps me to understand more mechanism of emacs. This issue is not a fatal error, it may just a display error. Again, thank you very much.